# Configuring ASP.NET Core data protection

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is this supposed to work?

```
string keyVaultName = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultName");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultName))
{
    AspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions = new AspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions();
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AspNetCoreDataProtection").Bind(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions);
    aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.BlobUriWithSasToken = null; // Doesn't work.

    builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.ConnectionString, aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.ContainerName, aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.BlobName)
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.KeyIdentifier), new DefaultAzureCredential())
        .SetApplicationName("Thingamajig")
        ;
}
else
{
    // https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/deployment/data_protection/
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#setapplicationname
    builder.Services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("Thingamajig");
}
```

It doesn't.
I'm getting spammed by Duende IdentityServer complaining about

> Error unprotecting key with kid 40A6DCC6859A61E76D727179AE4FFA72.
> The key {3582d55c-95b4-456e-bc63-68dedcced74f} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning

**Update**
Breakpoint with values.[image]

Comment: your code looks correct but you are setting the `BlobUriWithSasToken` to null.  If you're using a connection string for authentication, you may not need a SAS token, but make sure your blob storage authentication method matches your configuration. make sure you have separate key storage or that you're aware of which keys are being used where. If this value differs between application runs or instances, they won't be able to read each other's keys. Ensure that this value is consistent across your deployments. try to enable logging in your code to get more detail.

Comment: As far as I can tell `BlobUriWithSasToken` is broken and does not work therefore I am using the `ConnectionString` and `KeyIdentifier`.
This _data protection_ thing simply does not work and is therefore useless. Can it at least be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not work it must be disabled.
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-disable-data-protection-in-asp-net-core-cdf7cad28509